# Drush not recognized and internal or external command

Tags: drush

When I update Drush to Drush 9.1.0, the following error now appears:

```
'drush' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This issue has occurred on three different machines: two running Windows Server 2016 and one running Windows 10. I've read that it could be due to mismatched global and site Drush versions, but both versions are at 9.1.0. When I downgrade to Drush 8.x.x, it functions as normal. Both the global and site-specific Drush installs were installed with Composer. Are there any fixes for this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you install Drush Launcher? This seems like a PATH issue -- your command lines doesn't know where to find Drush 9.

> To be able to call drush from anywhere, install the Drush Launcher.
>   That is a small program which listens on your $PATH and hands control
>   to a site-local Drush that is in the /vendor directory of your
>   Composer project. If you skip this step, run Drush from Drupal root
>   via ../vendor/bin/drush. In that case Drush's bash integration and
>   custom prompt won't work.

from: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: I haven't installed Drush Launcher because I don't need it with Drush 8 so I assumed all would function the same with Drush 9.

Comment: Drush 9 is a big rewrite, so I wouldn't make any assumptions about what things will work the same.

Comment: Drush Launcher did it. It took a little bit of extra work to get it running on Windows, but I got it. Drush only runs successfully from the project root, not the site root or anywhere else in the site's file structure. Is that normal?

Comment: Great! Though that's normal... though I confess I am having a bunch of trouble with Drush 9_1 at the moment (after upgrading from a beta version). Wondering if I should try that (running from the project root) to see if that solves my problems. What happens when you try to run from the site root?

Comment: When I run from site-root, nothing happens. It's just stuck until I exit out of it.

Comment: Ok, not the same problem... try debugging? adding -d on a command? gives a little output as it goes.

Comment: Hey Blake, out of curiosity, does your Drupal site root have a composer.json in it? This was at the root of my issues with Drupal 9.1